# hover on a point in highcharts graph using playwright and typescript

Tags: typescript, highcharts, playwright

I am trying to automate hovering on a graph point in highcharts.
I succeeded to isolate the point element in the web console using an SVG xpath with this code-

```
     await page.hover(
    "//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker']//*[name()='path'][4])[2]"
     );
```

but received this error-

```
  page.hover: DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker']//*[name()='path'][4])[2]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Working with playwright and typescript.
Will be happy also to hear other possible solutions for hovering highcharts.
Below you can find the element's html info.  Thanks!

[element's html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neG0i.png)

Comment: Why don't you use the mouseOver event for it: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.mouseOver?

Comment: thanks, but this function creates the highcharts...I want to extract data from and hover or click the element from am existing chart.

Comment: I see. Using the mouseOver callback is the safer and advised solution, otherwise, you can loop through the DOM elements and add a onmouseover event - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5n63zdyb/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you'll need Playwright's `page.locator()` since this method is really helpful for task like this.
I prefer not to use XPath method since the syntax format is ugly and not reliable.

```
const pathLocator = page.locator('svg > g[class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker"] > path')
await pathLocator.nth(4).hover()
```

Don't forget to select this solution as the right answer if you find this is helpful and correct.

Comment: Thanks, it dosen't work. debug mode state "Uncaught ReferenceError: page is not defined"... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After digging more online I succeded... here is the solution for the community-

```
   import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import helper from "../../../shared/helper";
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login.pages';



test('click on each column in highcarts', async ({ page }) => {
    test.setTimeout(180000);
    const {url, emailInput, passwordInput, loginButton} = helper.loginPage;
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.fill(emailInput, helper.users.automationUser.email);
    await page.fill(passwordInput, helper.users.automationUser.password);
    await page.click(loginButton);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ url: helper.companiesPage.url });
    await page.goto("https://dview2-dev.3dsignals.io/Samson/reports/idle_classification_report");
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })

    const elementsCount = await page.$$eval("(//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group'])[3]//*[name()='rect']", (el) => el.length);
    for (var index= 0; index < elementsCount ; index++) {
            await page.locator("(//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group'])[3]//*[name()='rect'] >> nth=" + index).hover();
            await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

    }        
});
```

Good luck to everyone!